# How do I remove all List elements from an Array?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have to remove all `List` elements from the `Array`.

```
scala> var numbers=Array("321","3232","2401","7777","666","555")
numbers: Array[String] = Array(321, 3232, 2401, 7777, 666, 555)

scala> var nums=List("321","3232","2401")
nums: List[String] = List(321, 3232, 2401)
```

Would `filter` be useful here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `numbers.diff(nums)` - as simple as that:

```
scala> var numbers = Array("321", "3232", "2401", "7777", "666", "555")
numbers: Array[String] = Array(321, 3232, 2401, 7777, 666, 555)

scala> var nums = List("321", "3232", "2401")
nums: List[String] = List(321, 3232, 2401)

scala> numbers diff nums
res0: Array[String] = Array(7777, 666, 555)
```

Answer (score 2):

Truly using `diff` leads to a neat and simple approach; some other, more verbose ways,

```
numbers filterNot { nums.contains(_) }

for ( n <- numbers if !nums.contains(n) ) yield n
```